# Compare many pairs of bools

Tags: c#, boolean

I am unsure of the terminology of the comparison I would like to make:

```
if(test1 == true && test2 == true || test2 == true && test3 == true || test3 == true && test4 == true...)
{
   //Do stuff
}
```

Is there an effective method/function to accomplish this? Otherwise I'm going to have a really long if statement. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Not if you have them all as variables. If you have alot of bools they should probably be in a list. Otherwise, if-statements can be long sometimes, then just linebreak after each || to make the code more readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var tests = new[] { test1, test2, test3, test4, ... };

for (int i = 0; i < tests.Length - 1; ++i) {
   if (tests[i] && tests[i + 1]) {
     // Do stuff
     break;
   }
}
```

Comment: call me loopy, but this seemed to be efficient enough. Like I said, I had a bunch of comparisons to make...

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to specify the `==true` part. It can be written as follows.

```
if(test1 && test2 || test2 && test3 || test3 && test4...)
{
   //Do stuff
}
```

If you want to simplify the expression itself, I suggest you look into boolean algebra and the [reduction of boolean expressions](http://sandbox.mc.edu/~bennet/cs110/boolalg/simple.html).

This is an expression of the form `AB + BC + CD + ...`. One reduction you could perform is as follows.

```
AB + BC = B(A+C) = B && (A || C)
```

A [list](http://www.dotnetperls.com/list) can also be used to store all the different boolean values and one iteration over them can be used to compute this. This helps readability, while performance/memory footprint is **almost unchanged** or only slightly degraded.

Answer (score 0):

You may just use `if(test1 && test2 || ...)`

or you may break it down into multiple steps

Do you have all separate variables or are they in a array/list
In the latter case, you may iterate them over a loop.

```
bool result = true;

foreach (bool b  in boolArray)
{
   result = result op b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply eliminate the boolean comparisons

`if( (test1 && test2))` is equivalent to `if(test1 == true && test2 == true)`

Answer (score 0):

The shortest I can think of would be this:

```
if((test2 && (test1 || test3)) || (test3 && test4)) {
    //Do Stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont mind put your bool's in a list and use it by linq

e.g.

```
bool test1 = true;
bool test2 = true;
bool test3 = true;
bool test4 = true;

List<bool> booList = new List<bool>{test1, test2, test3, test4};

bool isTrue = booList.All(b => b == true); //This will return true


bool test5 = false;
booList.Add(test5);


bool isFalse = booList.All(b => b == true); //This will return false
```

PS: I don't know what would be the performance compare to if statement

Answer (score 0):

```
char test[x]

... test[x] init ...

i=0
res=0

while( i < x-2 )
{
    res |= test[i] && test[i+1]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using C#, you can treat boolean values with logic. :)

if bool1, then buy some ice-cream;

if bool1 does not exist, then don't buy some ice-cream;

when comparing a value to 0, you can use the not operator (!).

if(!bool1)MessageBox.Show("No ice-cream mate");

same goes for when comparing against 0, just don't apply the not operator (!).

if(bool1)MessageBox.Show("ice-cream :D");

Sorry if I made it confusing.

So, to add to the other's posts, the following would be fit.

if(bool1 && bool2 || bool1 && bool3)MessageBox.Show("ice-cream!");

Answer (score 0):

The LINQ way (assuming that the values are in an array):

```
bool result = (from index in Enumerable.Range(0, tests.Length - 1)
               where tests[index] && tests[index + 1]
               select index).Any();
```

Answer (score 0):

Or would translate to LINQ.ANY if you can put the bool in a list

```
List<bool> booList = new List<bool> { true, true, true, true };
            bool isTrue = booList.Any(b => b);
            Console.WriteLine(isTrue.ToString());
            booList = new List<bool> { true, true, false, false };
            isTrue = booList.Any(b => b);
            Console.WriteLine(isTrue.ToString());
            booList = new List<bool> { false, false, false, false };
            isTrue = booList.Any(b => b);
            Console.WriteLine(isTrue.ToString());
```